# the symfony security does not protect the route

Tags: api, symfony, authentication, jwt

with symfony, I set up a security system with jwt.
I manage to connect and I get the token.

I configured /api to be protected by token so.
only it doesn't protect it. i can access it in fo

security.yaml

```yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true         
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ~/api
            stateless: true
           
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator               

    access_control:
        - { path: ~/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }    
        - { path: ~/auth/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }        


when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

```php
#[Route('/api')]
class DataController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/locations', name: 'app_locations', methods: 'GET')]
    public function locations(LocationRepository $locationRepository): Response
    {
```

GET http://localhost:8001/api/locations
I get the data, but it should not allow me access.

Answer (score 4):

Your access_control seems to be the issue.

Try editing with:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }    
    - { path: ^/auth/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

Which should match your `/api/locations` route.

In your code, you have `~/api` which does not match `/api/location`, that's why we are using `^/api` to match anything that follows `/api`.

You can see more advanced example in the [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html).